# Sort tuples in Prolog

Tags: sorting, prolog

When I sort [(101,a),(42,b),(85,b)] is Prolog with `sort([(101,a),(42,b),(85,b)],X).` is get `X = [ (42, b), (85, b), (101, a)].` But how come? Does Prolog recognize the tuples and sort them on the first element and then on the second element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really simply look at the exact documentation of the Prolog you are using. In SWI-Prolog, for example, sorting is on "standard order". For compound terms (as you are using), it is first arity, then name, then recursively arguments. So in your case, yes, it is sorted first on first and then on second argument.

By the way, ISO `sort` should remove duplicates, not that you get surprised by it.

And strictly speaking, there are no "tuples" in Prolog. What you have there is the functor `,` with arity 2 (or, `,/2`). Look at this:

```
2 ?- write_canonical((42, b)).
','(42,b)
true.
```

Comment: Functors are everywhere... Damn you Haskell, I can't stop seeing this stuff all around me now... Was it always there and I was blind? Ahh I'm getting a headache thinking about it, I can't unsee...

Comment: That I have been permanently changed against my will, Haskell should come with more severe warnings...

Comment: "Functor" in Prolog doesn't really mean the same thing as it does in Haskell. Here it just means the atom name of the structure. In Haskell it means a type that is a member of the `Functor` typeclass (i.e., a type that supports the `fmap` operation). Don't worry, Prolog will also permanently change you. :)

Comment: +1, Just a nit in passing:  `sort([X,1],[1,1])` succeeds with `X = 1`. Since term order includes variables, we have such non-logical behavior. [More details](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#sort).

Answer (score -1):

Your assumption seems reasonable. We can check some documentation, personally I like the [documentation for ciao](http://ciao-lang.org/legacy/files/ciao/ciao.pdf).

See page 235, then page 115. Notice you could also sort by keys.

You should be aware that some people consider using this kind of predicates (non-declarative) a bad practice. Basically there are two terms in this predicate, one must be grounded and the other one must not, so in fact this is a function and not a logical predicate. Those worried for the "purity" of logic programming would probably find a workaround not to use that.

Comment: Thank you! How is it not logical to say Y is the sorted list of X in sort(X,Y)? I mean, every predicate to sort will need a list and an output though? Or am I wrong in this?

Comment: Logical is member(X,Y), so that none of both terms need to be grounded. A logical predicate establishes a relation between a group of variables, there is nothing like "input" or "output" and it is not used to "sort", it only establishes that X and Y have exactly the same elements and that the elements in Y are sorted (which is a relation between them). At least this is from the "purest logic programming approach", at the core this is just "programming with backtracking and variable unifications".

Comment: You cannot escape "backtracking and unification" even in something as trivial as member: it will unify X with the elements of Y in an order defined by the specific implementation of member. In this sense Prolog is never purely logical, which is why logical programming and Prolog are usually discussed separately.

Comment: I cannot take seriously the suggestion that people avoid sorting and use workarounds to ensure their Prolog programs remain logically pure. Not every predicate is worth defining for every possible instantiation pattern, but you certainly could furnish an implementation for `sort(-Unsorted, +Sorted)` if you felt it necessary and helpful. There's certainly a logical, if non-deterministic, relationship between unsorted and sorted lists.

Comment: @Boris why would anyone want to escape "bactracking and unification"?

Comment: @DanielLyons why would you take seriously a suggestion nobody did? [This link](http://www.kmjn.org/notes/prolog_lost_steam.html) may also be interesting for you.

Comment: In prolog, no one could even if they wanted to, for any useful program. You seemed to claim the opposite.

Comment: @Boris How would I suggest something impossible? Prolog is supposed to be logic programming, and supposedly programmers write in logic, while in fact they are writing programs that (at the core) use backtracking and unification. I cannot understand why you both misinterpreted my message so much and thought to be understanding it. Many universities use Prolog to teach logic programming, that's why I think detailing that is relevant for anyone learning Prolog (possibly as a means to learn logic programming or declarative programming).

Comment: In the context of this question (sorting) the last paragraph is misplaced and strange. The takeaway is that one should avoid sorting. You seem to be saying that isn't what you're saying, and instead you're apparently trying to make a general remark about programming in Prolog. The remark, taken in general terms, isn't wrong, but it also isn't germane and in the context it's more misleading than illuminating.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the article, it is very interesting and a good read. Not sure what it has to do with the discussion though.

Comment: @DanielLyons Basically the last paragraph is a remark about logic programming, even though the question specifies Prolog. These are two different things that people use to merge. Therefore it is a remark, an additional clarification for those interested in logic programming, who may read this question and answers, and even OP if interested in logic programming. That is a non-declarative predicate that should definitively be avoided in logic programming (a type of declarative programming). I think it's germane because Prolog is often used to teach logic programming, and people use to mix both.

Comment: I misunderstood you, indeed. The linked article is interesting, too, but it misses two very big points. First, the fragmentation of Prolog implementations; second, the knuckle-headed way it is introduced to students in universities (that is, as a logical programming language, which it isn't, ultimately, and without much _practical_ use). These are today the two biggest reasons why Prolog lost steam. With implementations like SWI-Prolog, however, I won't be too surprised if the trend turns around again.

Comment: I don't see Prolog gaining steam any time soon, it's still teached as part of the logical programming paradigm and it's nice for constraint based programming (which is not as great outside of the Prolog world). E.g. Haskell is also very nice, but Scala is raising by combining OOP and functional in the Java platform, similarly to what Clojure does. If we see any strength in logic programming  anytime soon I think that will be due to similar reasons. Prolog without logic programming is nice, but not great, as a language.